# Python Bigquery create temp table

Tags: python, google-bigquery, temp-tables

When I create temp table via python, an error throws
400 Use of CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE requires a script or session
How can I create a session?

```
from google.colab import auth
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.colab import data_table
client = bigquery.Client(project=project, location = location)


client.query('''
create temp table t_acquisted_users as
select *
from table_a
limit 10
''').result()
```

Comment: Temp tables in BigQuery are only usable in that script that you are using, if you add a  `select * from t_acquisted_users` after, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a session using the BigQuery API using the `create_session` parameter in a job config, for example:
`job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig(create_session=True)`

More details on this excellent article:
https://dev.to/stack-labs/bigquery-transactions-over-multiple-queries-with-sessions-2ll5

Answer (score 1):

That's how I fix it in quick. Awaiting others provide a better answer

```
# create session
client0 = bigquery.Client(project=project, location=location)
job = client0.query(
    "SELECT 1;",  # a query can't fail
    job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig(create_session=True)
)
session_id = job.session_info.session_id
job.result()

# set default session
client = bigquery.Client(project=project, location=location, 
    default_query_job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    connection_properties=[
          bigquery.query.ConnectionProperty(
          key="session_id", value=session_id
      )
    ]
))
```